# DarkActionBar - Light Tab Background?

Tags: android, tabs, styles

I am using Holo.Light.DarkActionBar with these modifications.

```
<style name="myTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBar.Text</item>
    <item name="@android:attr/actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabStyle</item>
</style>


<style name="TabStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText.Inverse">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ECECEC</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#222</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBar.Text</item>
</style>
```

So my Action Bar is Dark, and my Tab background is light, with dark text.  The problem is when I go into Landscape mode it puts the tab in the action bar, which is ok, but now there is dark text in the dark action bar.

**I am looking for one of these two solutions:**

1. Text Color is different whether portrait (dark) or landscape (light).
2. OR, the Tab Background is all dark, and the text is all light.

EDIT:  I would think that the DarkActionBar theme would include the tabs as well?

Here is my tab setup:

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```